# TypeError i is null in jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

Okay so I know the error doesn't come form jquery.

I have an ajax answer with some content formatted in a set of HTML table rows, that I want to append to my table :

```
$.ajax().done(function() {
    ...
    table.append(response);
    ...
});
```

Easy, right ? Well, not really. I get this error :

> TypeError: i is null

So to debug I logged the response content :

```
...
console.log(response);
table.append(response);
...
```

`response` is not empty. Not at all : `<tr><td>178</td>......</td></tr>`.
Actually, I'm pretty sure there's a limit to the size you can append to the DOM in one go. because just in the console, when I expand the response log, it take one second or two to display...

I know why the response is so big : it contains my answer and some error informations generated by the couple plugins I use, but I need to display it to get readable debug info on the server ajax request processing (why, where, how does my code crash ??)...

So my question is : does anyone know if there is a limit to the JQuery append size, and especially which value it is ? I couldn't find it on google...

**EDIT:**
I managed to display the content of the response with :

```
table.append(response.substr(0));
```

Then I could fix the bug. (For those who wanna know : it was a syntax error in a regex)

Comment: What is the content of `response`? There is no specific size limit on the DOM, but obviously it will start to hurt performance if you're dumping too much data in to it. Seeing a more complete sample of your code would help here.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough context for the above code, but I strongly suspect that it's null because you're trying to append the data before the ajax call returns.  You are not running into a limit on the amount of content that can be appended to the DOM.

Comment: will you please write your response?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
I call the `append()` method in the `done()` part of my ajax call (and after the console log). I managed to display (and fix) my back-end errors using `substr()`.

I don't know why I got an error when displaying the whole string however...